# How to get a round images in html emails working in Outlook with VML?

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, vml

I'm trying to get a circular image to appear in an HTML email. So far it's working in all clients except for Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2016 (Windows 7).

I found some VML tutorial that says this should do the trick:

```
<v:oval style="width:100;height:100">
<v:fill src="https://www.placebear.com/100/100.jpg" type="frame">
<v:/fill>
</v:oval>
```

However I tried it with conditional comments

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
  <v:oval style="width:100;height:100">
    <v:fill src="https://www.placebear.com/100/100.jpg" type="frame">
    <v:/fill>
  </v:oval>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

and nothing appeared.

Anybody have a working solution? Border-radius is doing the trick for every othe client but Outlook, because of course...

Comment: The code you posted if everything apart from Outlook. Use Gwesolo's code to display it in Outlook. You can use both, one for Outlook and one for non Outlook as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest changing your Outlook conditionals to this.

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>

<![endif]-->
```

Currently, you are hiding it from Outlook. If the VML proves too troublesome I'd recommend using a rounded image asset on a transparent background.